# Does eclipse link provide storage for xml data type

Tags: xml, jpa, eclipselink

I have a problem at which i need to store a field(column) in a certain Entity as xml data type and deal with them using jpa (eclipse link).

```
Does eclipse link provide a way to deal with xml other than no sql?

Does using no sql require the need of using different type of data
source and does that mean I cannot use a jta data source to deal with other normal entity?
Does using xml data type have bad impact on performance?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use more than SQL in JPA, which EclipseLink implements, you should take a look at JDO, a more comprehensive persistence option. JDO is used for many types of data storage, like XML, NoSQL db etc...

Google uses JDO as well.

Here's a link with more details: http://www.datanucleus.org/documentation/products/accessplatform.html

Comment: Do u have direct answer to my question specially if it can be done using jpa. it is not efficient to read and understand complete api(JDO) to solve such a mere problem

Comment: From what I know, JPA is meant only for relational databases. JDO is 99% the same with JPA, just that it has more features and flexibility. Take a look here: https://db.apache.org/jdo/jdo_v_jpa.html

Comment: so it is not possible to use xml data type with jpa